# Increasing the height of div dynamically if page width increases

Tags: css, responsive-design, frontend

In my **CSS** I would like to:

- Have the **div** never descend below a height (min-height)
- Have the **div** never exceed a certain height (max-height)
- If I increase the page width I want the **div** height to dynamically increase (or decrease if I'm decreasing the page width).

something like:

```
div{
  min-height: 10vw;
  max-height: 30vw;
  height: calc(??);
}
```

Is this achievable?

Comment: It works the way you want it. and there is no need for height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use Js? if you use js its possible with window.innerWidth and assign it to element.
Forexample:

```
let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
document.getElementById("myDynamicHeight").style.height = `${windowWidth}px`;
```